# Logical Proposition simplification

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm Trying to simplify this:

$$ [(¬p \vee ¬q)\to¬(r \vee s)] \wedge ¬s \wedge r$$

so far, I got into this:

$$ [(p \wedge q) \vee (¬r \wedge ¬s)] \wedge r \wedge ¬s$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** $(p\land q)\lor r\equiv(p\lor r)\land (q\lor r)$.

Comment: Thank you sir, I realized the solution was pretty simple.

Comment: You're welcome!